# Nop Commerce No Index

Tags: seo, nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce 3.3 I want search engines to disallow my site to be indexed. I created a robot.txt file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I wrote that in robots.txt file and then I placed to the wwwroot folder. I just want to know does this step in enough to stop indexing or do I have to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough but it does not physically block bots. It's just a request.

And it does not technically stop indexing. It asks the bots not to read the content.

Saying that, Google will generally keep it out of the search results as long as you have this in place from the start.

Comment: My reason to use that is just I am putting my site on development phase online don't want any search engine to index my site until it is complete and I will allow through bots and other methods..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these two options in "General And Miscellaneous Settings" can help you:

- Store closed
- Allow an admin to view the closed store

Comment: Yes it will but in store close I think google will index it.. However, I asked from nopcommerce team they said just put the robots file in root directory and nothing is needed..